# Building static HTML for pageserror: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, gatsby

I've gatsby project which works fine and also have 404 page, but either I get the error during `gatsby build` or open the browser after successfully completed the build process:

```
Building static HTML for pageserror: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory
```

if the error I didn't get during the `gatsby build` time then I have to get on the browser when  run `gatsby serve` and open browser:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/project/public/404.html'
```

Comment: try to add 404 page

Comment: @BloodyLogic
What happend when you run `gatsby clean` and then `gatsby build`, `gatsby serve`?

Comment: @ShinaBR2 already tried `rm -rf node_module .cache public` but didn't help me, it was working some time ago though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## workaround 1

add `404.js` or `404.tsx` file inside `pages` folder if you don't

1. Try to uninstall the `build` `.cache`, and `node_modules`.
2. `yarn add pkg.json` `npm install *`
3. pass all the required props to the layout (comp) in all the pages that it was used.
4. run the `gatsby develop` before `gatsby build`

## workaround 2

probably you're using `React.lazy` `suspense` in your component which doesn't support server-side render, you need to remove it by any possible way.
then try this should work!

[Want to use React.lazy in Gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63066974/how-to-use-react-lazy-in-gatsby/63066975#63066975)

Answer (score 5):

```
// clean gatsby cache
gatsby clean
// delete node modules, cache and public folder.
rm -rf node_module .cache public
// reinstall node modules
npm install
// run gatsby in develop mode
gatsby develop
// build the gatsby project
npm run build
// serve the building project.
gatsby serve
```

Comment: **Even just `gatsby clean` will solve this type of thing.**

Also, I would recommend running your dev command as `gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0` which allows live mobile testing while connected and on the same network.

Answer (score 1):

If the above answers don't work for you (didn't for me), Gatsby keeps a copy of a config.json here `~/.config/gatsby/config.json`.

Deleting the file made it work for me.

[Relevant Github issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/27338) from the Gatsby repo