# How to use React.lazy in Gatsby

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, gatsby

As using `React.lazy` in Gatsby you'll get error when making `production`( `gatsby build`), what is the best way to use `React.lazy` and `suspense` in Gatsby Project

Answer (score 13, accepted):

React.lazy and Suspense are still not ready for server-side rendering, but they can still be used by checking that the code is executed only on the client. While this solution is inferior to loadable-components, that works both on server side and client, it still provides an alternative for dealing with client-side only packages, without an added dependency. Remember that the following code could break if executed without the isSSR guard.

```
import React from "react"
const ClientSideOnlyLazy = React.lazy(() =>
  import("../components/ClientSideOnly")
)
const MyPage = () => {
  const isSSR = typeof window === "undefined"
  return (
    <>
      {!isSSR && (
        <React.Suspense fallback={<div />}>
          <ClientSideOnlyLazy />
        </React.Suspense>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Try following [this guide on gatsbyjs.com](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/using-client-side-only-packages/), if the above doesn't work for you

Comment: any suggestion why laze-Suspense works when running "gatsby develop" but "gatsby build" fails? what difference does it make?

Comment: @sale108 Gatsby does not run SSR in develop mode by default. This has caused some users headaches when they deploy gatsby apps to find that there are production-only issues due to SSR. However, you can run SSR mode adding the **DEV_SSR** flag to your `gatsby-config.js`:
`module.exports = {
  flags: {
    DEV_SSR: true
  },
  plugins: [...]
}`

Read more about in Gatsby discussion: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/28138